# Flutter build failed after upgrading to Flutter v3

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-upgrade

I've updated my app from v2.2.10 to Flutter 3 and it shows the following error.

```
     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * Where:
[        ] Script '/Users/user/fvm/versions/3.0.0/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.
[        ] > Process 'command '/Users/user/fvm/versions/3.0.0/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 2m 56s
```

Things I've tried to resolve the issue

- upgraded the dependencies
- run flutter clean
- deleted the build folder
- invalidated and cleared the caches of Android Studio
- upgraded Gradle version
- run flutter doctor: No issues

So basically I've done all the possible solutions that could come to my mind. Is there anyone who faced this issue?

Here is the content of my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MicrosoftDeviceSDK/DuoSDK-Public/_packaging/Duo-SDK-Feed/maven/v1'
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the content of my app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig null
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig null
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
       //flavor details
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.6.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try `flutter create .` then `flutter clean` and run the app

Answer (score 0):

Did you try command `dart fix --apply`? And please show you gradle file content

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. I've edited the question and added the content of build.gradle

Comment: For me the thing was to delete `android/app/build` folder and run `flutter clean`.

Comment: If it won't help. Show content of `android/app/build.gradle` file

Comment: Added the app level gradle file to the question

Comment: Delete your `pubspec.lock` -> `flutter clean` (I know you did this) -> check and remove unused imports (important) -> `flutter pub get`

Comment: tried that as well. No luck(

Comment: Try create new flutter project -> move lib folder and pubspec.yaml -> move code with required dependencies in build.gradle

Comment: that showed some compile-time errors. I fixed those, and I got the same error on running the app

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
flutter channel stable
 
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: I'm on a stable channel, tried upgrading as well

Comment: Can you show `android/app/build.gradle`?

Comment: try this too => flutter pub cache repair  or      ./gradlew build

Comment: no result with that(